# Preventing a RichTextBox operation from being added to the control's Undo stack

Tags: c++-cli, richtextbox, undo

Editing a RichTextBox control's text (more specifically, modifying selection font/color) programmatically seems to be tracked in the control's built in undo stack. Is there a way, short of writing my own undo/redo "manager", to prevent certain actions/operations from being added to the undo stack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No cando.  At best you can flush the undo stack completely by sending EM_SETUNDOLIMIT twice.  EM_SETTEXTEX offers the same option with the ST_DEFAULT flag.  Surely not what you want.  Look at ScintillaNET for a real editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you came here when searching for a WPF c# answer you have a good one here [Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042980/is-there-a-way-to-group-or-temporarily-disable-the-undo-history-for-a-richtextbo/32043032)

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can easily do this by implementing some of the ITextDocument interface and sending tomSuspend and tomResume as a count argument to the Undo handler.