# How can I remove an action from undo stack of a RichTextBox control?

Tags: c#, wpf, stack, richtextbox, undo

It seems that there is this `ClearUndo()` method in a RichTextBox in Windows Forms (see [system.windows.forms.textboxbase.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.clearundo.aspx)).

I need something similar in `RichTextBox Control`. This is because (as it is mentioned here: [Preventing a RichTextBox operation from being added to the control's Undo stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534946/preventing-a-richtextbox-operation-from-being-added-to-the-controls-undo-stack)) every change is added to the RichTextBox's undo stack.

I like to override `OnTextChanged` event and remove some of these changes from Uno stack. How can I do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 13):

You can emulate `ClearUndo()` for WPF `RichTextBox` control with the following code:

```
richTextBox.IsUndoEnabled = false;
richTextBox.IsUndoEnabled = true;
```

But there's no way you can control any particular actions in the `Undo` list.

If you still want to implement your own `Undo/Redo` mechanism, the easiest and the most straightforward way is to store in an array the whole text of the control on each significant text change. But I would advise it only if you're not planning to edit large text with the control.