# Is there a way to group or temporarily disable the undo history for a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I'm currently wrestling with Tables inside RichTextBoxs in WPF. In WPF, tables don't have rows and columns, they just have rows, each having a certain number of cells. When a user presses the "Add Column" button, my program adds a new cell to each row.

The problem with using this method is after a user adds a column, if they press undo, it removes each cell one by one, obviously not what the user would expect.

Does anyone know a way to temporarily disable the addition of actions to the undo queue, or a way to group undo actions, or any other solution to my problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to *group* undo actions (rather than disable undo entirely), you can group a set of programmatic changes via [`TextBoxBase.BeginChange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.beginchange%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then, after making the changes, [`TextBoxBase.EndChange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.endchange%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), i.e.:

```
        richTextBox.BeginChange();
        try
        {
            // Add column

            // For each row, add a cell to the column.
        }
        finally
        {
            richTextBox.EndChange();
        }
```

Or, equivalently, you can call [`TextBoxBase.DeclareChangeBlock()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.declarechangeblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inside a [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement:

```
        using (richTextBox.DeclareChangeBlock())
        {
            // Add column

            // For each row, add a cell to the column.
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can disable `undo` by setting `IsUndoEnabled` property to `false` or you can limit the undo by using `UndoLimit`. you can disable the undo by setting this property to `0`, ie., `UndoLimit="0"`

```
<RichTextBox  Name="myRitchTextBox" IsUndoEnabled="False" />
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was after. I still need the users to be able to undo after the program had fiddled with the table.