# temporarily stopping undo event capturing in textbox - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Evening Everyone,
I have a custom richtextbox where I do formatting and such to words as users type in the box.  All works great...except when they hit ctrl+z or use the undo functionality.  Instead of undoing their word they just typed, it goes back and starts to undo all of the formatting that was programmatically added.

So, is there a way to stop the "Undo capturing" (not sure what to call it...?) during the progrommatic changes then turn it back on after?

Here is an example that I can't find how to do:

```
User types word
----------------
pause adding to undo buffer
programmatic changes to formatting
start adding to undo buffer
----------------
user hits ctrl+z and word they just typed is undone
```

Thanks

Comment: Just call RichTextBox.ClearUndo() after you made changes yourself.  Do tag your question properly, nobody can tell what GUI class library you use.

Comment: added the tag...That isn't what I was looking for tho as that clears everything in the undo buffer.  I want them to be able to undo the word they just typed but I do not want all of the formatting actions in the buffer.  so here would be the sequence:  type word->format word programmatically->user hits ctrl+z->word they just typed is undone

Comment: You are asking for a pony.  Libraries that implement a real text editor or word processor are widely available.

Comment: You've [already said that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2614526/11683) @HansPassant ;)